# alternative to history.replaceState in node-red

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I'm currently developing an application using Node-RED. I want to change the URL without redirecting to another domain. I've some experiences with basic JavaScript and I know in JS it's possible to use `history.replaceState()` to achieve this. But the `history` object is not available in Node-RED. If I'm trying to use `.replaceState()` in my flow or in one of my own nodes it will output a reference error (`ReferenceError: history is not defined`).

I've read that `global` is something similar to the JS `window` object, but I guess this doesn't help me in this case, does it? Is there an alternative to `history.replaceState()` in Node-RED?

Comment: It's really not clear where you are trying to do this. Is this in a web app served from Node-RED, the Node-RED Dashboard or inside the Node-RED editor?

Comment: @hardillb I tried it in the Node-RED editor in a function node when calling http://example.com:1880. I also tried to create an own node but the result is the same.

Comment: You can not change the URL of the editor from within the editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any code running in a function node is running on the server side of Node-RED not in the editor, you can not mask/change the URL of the editor from with in a flow.

Comment: Hmm okay, then I have to find another way. Thank you.